# uninitialized value error in perl

Tags: perl

I'm pretty new to perl (and programming in general but I'm used to Python).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

my $simple_variable = "string";
print my $simple_variable;
```

Basically I want to know why this script returns an uninitialized value error, since the variable is clearly defined.

Thanks

Comment: You have learned about scoping!! The classic online references for learning more are [Coping with Scoping](http://perl.plover.com/FAQs/Namespaces.html) and the oft read [PerlMonks node](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=66677) on Variable Scoping in Perl. I found that the node id number was easily memorizable :-)

Comment: You want `print "$simple_variable\n";` You must put that `\n` on the end because `print` doesn't do that automatically for you.

Answer (score 3):

`my` creates a variable and initializes it to undef (scalars) or empty (arrays and hashes). It also returns the variable it creates.

As such,

```
print my $simple_variable;
```

is the same thing as

```
my $simple_variable = undef;
print $simple_variable;
```

You meant to do

```
my $simple_variable = "string";
print $simple_variable;
```

I'm not sure why you are asking this because Perl already told you as much. Your program outputs the following:

```
"my" variable $simple_variable masks earlier declaration in same scope at a.pl
        line 6 (#1)
    (W misc) A "my", "our" or "state" variable has been redeclared in the
    current scope or statement, effectively eliminating all access to the
    previous instance.  This is almost always a typographical error.  Note
    that the earlier variable will still exist until the end of the scope
    or until all closure referents to it are destroyed.
```

Note how the new declaration has the effect of "effectively eliminating all access to the previous instance".